# Find the Selector of a Class method

Tags: objective-c

I'm quite a newbie in Objective C, though I have some background in Java reflection.

Here, I have a classic class method **findAll** that find all the domain objects from the database. The class **Univers** directly inherits from **DomainObject**

```
@interface DomainObject : NSObject

  - (NSString *) execute : (NSString*) method  withJson:(NSString*)json;
  + (NSString*)findAll: (NSString*)json;

@end

@implementation DomainObject

  - (NSString *) execute: (NSString*) method  withJson:(NSString*)json{

      method = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", method, @":"]; 
      //method is 'findAll:'
      NSString* result =  [ self performSelector: 
          NSSelectorFromString(method) withObject:json];// Error here
      return result;    
  }
@end
```

The code was working when findAll was NOT a class method (ie -findAll declaration), but now I have the error : NSInvalidArgumentException -[Univers findAll:]
It clearly seems that the runtime is looking for an instance method.

Any idea to find my class method ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of calling

```
NSString* result =  [self performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(method) withObject:json];
```

you need to call

```
NSString* result =  [[self class] performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(method) withObject:json];
```

for class methods.

After all it's the object instance's class that supposed to be calling the method, not the instance itself.

Short explanation: `NSObject` implements `- (Class)class;` (not to be mistaken with `+ (Class)class` of similar effect, which `NSObject` implements, too!) which returns the Class object of your instance object. Keep in mind that in Objective-C in addition to plain instance objects, Classes are actual objects, too: objects of type `Class`, that is (vs. `id`, `NSObject`, …).

See the documentation for the `-class` method [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/class).

---

Btw, you should probably wrap your method call into an conditional block to prevent exceptions caused by calls to missing methods.

```
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(method);
if ([[self class] respondsToSelector:selector]) {
    NSString* result =  [[self class] performSelector:selector withObject:json];
}
```

---

In general it's a common pattern in Objective-C to call an object's class method by receiving the class object via `[object class]`.

Consider this case of a class called `Foo` implementing a convenience method for returning an autporeleased instance of itself (to be called via: `Foo *newFoo = [Foo foo];`):

While it would certainly be possible to implement said method like this (after all we know the object's class name, right?):

```
+ (id)foo {
    return [[[Foo alloc] init] autorelease];
}
```

the correct way is this:

```
+ (id)foo {
    return [[[self alloc] init] autorelease];
}
```

As the first one would cause problems with polymorphism in subclasses (Such as a subclass called `FooBar`, for which it should clearly be `[FooBar alloc] …`, not `[Foo alloc] …`. Luckily `[[self class] alloc]` solves this dynamically).
While this is clearly not the right place for a thorough explanation of this (rather offtopic one might say) it's certainly worth noting/warning about, imho.

Comment: I don't think good explanations to a beginner are offtopic :)

Comment: `return [[[[self class] alloc] init] autorelease];` should just be `return [[[self alloc] init] autorelease];`. `[self class]` is the exact same as `self` in a class mehtod

Comment: @user102008: You're absolutely right. I blame copy & paste. ;) Fixed.

Comment: You can also just write `self.class` instead of `[self class]`.